# How to reference projects/libraries in Xcode 12.X?

Tags: swift, xcode

Apologies for a question that has been asked in various forms before, but i'm still not understanding what I need to do.

I'm new to Apple development having spend most of the last 10 years working with .NET.

I've been writing a group of libraries that in the future I will want to reference in various applications.  To begin with, I created a workspace, which worked great.  As long as I remembered to build each project, i was able to easily reference them using the import statement.

However now I find myself in the position that I want to reference my libraries from another application.

In .NET i would build each project and a .dll would be created in the output folder.
As far as I understand, the similar file is a lib.a file in swift - however it seems to build to some hidden folder that I can't see browsing in finder.

So onto the question:
If I have 3 libraries lib1, lib2 and lib3.
lib2 needs to reference lib1,
lib3 needs to reference lib2,
and my new application needs to reference lib3.

How do I go about adding the .a files to my projects and referencing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem here: https://betterprogramming.pub/create-swift-5-static-library-f1c7a1be3e45

To summarise: After building the project and the lib.a file being generated, you can right click and select "show in finder".  This takes you to the hidden folder where it has been built.

Finally, to reference your library in another project the Library Search Path should be copied to the Import Paths under Build Settings.